# No idea why my jquery will not post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have no idea why my jquery is not posting. I can see and click on the iputs but will not post. I am dumping all local and int traffic via wireshark but see nothing at all.

My logs look like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2016 22:14:35] "GET /control_panel.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2016 22:14:35] "GET /rocket.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2016 22:14:35] "GET /js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Here is sample script:

```
<script>
    $('#dsubmit').click(function(){
        var accessHash = document.getElementById("rocketHash").value;
        $.post("api.js", {rocketHash: accessHash, rocketDown: 'rocketDown'}, function(result){
            $("#rocketHashReturn").fadeIn();
            $("#rocketHashReturn").text(result);
            $("#rocketHashReturn").delay(250).fadeOut();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is jsfiddle of entire thing:

https://jsfiddle.net/0mpj7zc2/

I feel like it's probably something pretty stupid that I am overlooking.

Comment: Anything on the browser console? Is your `click` callback function being called at all?

Comment: Make sure you add you code inside document.ready `$(function(){ //your code  });`

Comment: @bipen looking at the fiddle, I don't think it is inside the doc's ready event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ya make sense. just that I didnt see the ready function in fiddle and in question so added a comment  :) :) . Also if the script is at the end of html, doucment.ready is not required.

Comment: Nothing on the browser console at all. Ill try the doc ready

Comment: Also if your code is same with what you have in fiddle. Then you better clean your code. You don't need multiple `<script></script>` just have one and add all of your javascript code in `$(function(){...});` inside one script tag . Also, you don't have to load jquery twice.

Comment: document . ready didnt help. unfortunately.

Comment: I literally used this same snippet on the login page. Without document.ready and it works fine. For whatver reason, this is just not POsting. Also not seeing anything at all in console.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind the click event.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dsubmit').click(function(){
        var accessHash = document.getElementById("rocketHash").value;
        $.post("api.js", {rocketHash: accessHash, rocketDown: 'rocketDown'},function(result){
        $("#rocketHashReturn").fadeIn();
        $("#rocketHashReturn").text(result);
        $("#rocketHashReturn").delay(250).fadeOut();
    });
  });


</script>
```

try like this. it should be work.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with that you're using input elements (without a type) to create your buttons to click on. Changing the inputs to divs or buttons and adding jquery to your fiddle made the click handlers work.

You probably shouldn't use input elements as buttons this way, only for the text input.

Comment: Hmm ok interesting. Ill give that a shot.

Comment: Hmm interesting ok, yea thats what it was. Ive done that before though which is weird. Totally messes up the CSS when I do that. No matter, I can change that. Thanks!

Comment: As q general tip, only use input elements for what they are supposed to be used. In this case, a <button> element would be much better and prevents getting into side cases like this, where inputs without a type automatically default to input type text, but since they're heavily styled, you don't notice it's a faulty text input.